# Trouble on error "couldn't find file 'ckeditor/override'" in my application.js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am using the [galetahub/ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) gem (version 4.0.6) in my Ruby on Rails 4 application. I follow the guide in its Readme file but when I add the `//= require ckeditor/override` manifest statement in my `application.js` file I get the following error:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound - couldn't find file 'ckeditor/override'
```

My `application.js` file is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require turbolinks
//
//= require ckeditor/override
//= require ckeditor/init
```

How can I solve the problem?

*Note*: Since I don't need to use upload functionality I skip instructions in the "[How generate models for store uploading files](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#how-generate-models-for-store-uploading-files)".

---

My `Gemfile` is:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.1.rc1'
...
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', :git => 'https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks.git'
gem 'ckeditor'
...
```

Answer (score 4):

please update your gem 'ckeditor' to the newest one.

run `bundle show` to check the gem version.

Add below in Gemfile:

```
gem "ckeditor", :git => "git@github.com:galetahub/ckeditor.git"
```

and then run `bundle update`

it works for me.

Comment: That worked for me in dev but tripped me up when deploying to heroku. You can't use the SSH url there because you get a bunch of
 
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

I found using 

gem 'ckeditor', :git => 'git://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.git'

worked for me.

Comment: Or even better: `gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'`

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue here, my gem ckeditor version is 4.0.6.

Using command

```
bundle open ckeditor
```

found that there is no override.js.erb file under app/assets/javascript/ckeditor, probably a mistake when publishing the gem? I don't know. I'm using the way suggested by *inruby*, and it works.

```
gem "ckeditor", :git => "https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.git"
```

Comment: The problems is caused because the version in the gem server is not the latest, (its the 4.0.6, but in githbub is the 4.0.7)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `override` because the actual file is `app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/override.js.erb`.

What happens if you don't include it?

Comment: Could you include your Gemfile? Maybe it's not in `production`?